# Can't double tap

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-3.0

I have a question I can't figure out myself for a long time. If I have a cube game object in Unity and I want to change it's color to red when I press the space key, all I have to do is write a script and write:

```
void Update()
{

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
    GameObject Cube = GameObject.FindWithTag("Cube");

    Cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
    }
}
```

But what if I want to change it's color to blue when I press the space key again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can use a variable `is_red` and check its value in your update. Or maybe I didn't understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color on the second click you can simply add a If-statement that checks if the color is already equal to the wanted color and if it is change it to another color.

**Example:**

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
    // Get Cube GameObject
    GameObject Cube = GameObject.FindWithTag("Cube");
    // Get the Cube Renderer
    Renderer rd = Cube.GetComponent<Renderer>();

    // Is the color equal to red if it already is,
    // change it to blue instead
    if (rd.material.color = Color.red) {
        rd.material.color = Color.blue;
    }
    else {
        rd.material.color = Color.red;
    }
}
```

**Unrelated:**

If the GameObject that has the Cube Tag stays the same GameObject over the game, I would advise you to rather "fetch" the GameObject and it's Renderer Component once at the start of the game instead of each time you press the space Key, to increase performance.

```cs
private GameObject cubeGO;
private Renderer cubeRD;

private void Start {
    // Get Cube GameObject
    cubeGO = GameObject.FindWithTag("Cube");
    // Get the Cube Renderer
    cubeRD = Cube.GetComponent<Renderer>();
}
```

You can now use these variables inise the `Input.GetKeyDown(){}`

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
    // Is the color equal to red if it already is,
    // change it to blue instead
    if (cubeRD.material.color = Color.red) {
        cubeRD.material.color = Color.blue;
    }
    else {
        cubeRD.material.color = Color.red;
    }
}
```